# Radio button is blinking

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am creating a project in which I have to take radio button for 3 fields, in my blade file I writed this code:

```
    {!! Form::label('is_kids_friendly','Kids Friendly:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('yes', 'value', null, ['class' => 'myClass'],'yes') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('no', 'value', null, ['class' => 'myClass'],'no') !!}
```

The radio buttons on output screen are blinking, when i hover over it, I can not click on any of them.

Is there any correction or solution to this?

Comment: please add `myClass` style CSS here also.

Comment: @Shailesh Katarmal CSS is not added yet!

Comment: Thanks @Shailesh Katarmal , the CSS was being conflicted.